# grunt warning on build (grunt-contrib-compass)

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compass

I used the yoeman generator-angular to build a project and now I am getting an error on the build. I am getting this error:

```
Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

    Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task

    Running "coffee:test" (coffee) task

    Done, without errors.

    Elapsed time
    coffee:test  20ms
    Total        23ms

    Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
    Copied 2 files

    Done, without errors.

    Elapsed time
    copy:styles  29ms
    Total        29ms

        Warning: 
        /My/Project/Directory/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js:261
          throw err;
                ^
        Error: spawn EACCES
            at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
            at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34) Used --force, continuing.
```

It seems to be happening after the coffee:test task and as to do with the grunt-contrib-compass plugin. I'm unable to find anything on stack exchange to help me.

I am running:

grunt-cli v0.1.8

grunt v0.4.1

npm 1.3.8

node v0.10.18

I tried updating the generator to no avail. I was hoping someone could help me?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, it looks like Compass is either not installed other not accessible. It got better when I made:

```
> gem install compass
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was getting the same error as Jeff and this did not solve the issue.